# Compare 2 dates which are selected using datepicker in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular11

I have 2 datepickers ion a form. I want an error to occur if the tillDate is less than fromDate.
This is how I am trying to do, but am not successful. How can I compare the 2 dates? Thank you

This is html

```
                       <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="standard">
                                <mat-label>From Date</mat-label>
                                <input matInput formControlName="fromDate" required (change)="onTillDate()"
                                    [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" > 
                                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                                <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                                <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('fromDate')" class="error-block">
                                   From Date is a required field
                                </mat-error>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="standard">
                                <mat-label>Till Date</mat-label>
                                <input matInput formControlName="tillDate" required 
                                    [matDatepicker]="pickerTillDate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" (change)="onTillDate()" >
                                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickerTillDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                                <mat-datepicker #pickerTillDate></mat-datepicker>
                              <mat-error *ngIf="tillDate.hasError('mismatch')" class="error-block" > Till Date should be equal to greater than From Date
                            </mat-error>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

this is ts file

```
  onTillDate(){
      const startDate =  (moment(this.fromDate.value)).toDate();
      const endDate =(moment(this.tillDate.value)).toDate();
    if(endDate < startDate ){
      this.tillDate.setErrors({mismatch:true});
    }
    else
    {
      this.tillDate.setErrors(null);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you considered library https://momentjs.com/? It is really easy to use.

Comment: I did not know about it, Will give it a try,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Angular has builtin formatDate method so you can use it to format your date and also compare it simply like below code:

In your component.ts file:

```
   date1 = formatDate(inputDate1,'yyyy-MM-dd','en_US');
   date2  = formatDate(inputDate2,'yyyy-MM-dd','en_US');

   if(date1>date2){
     console.log('---date1 is greater----');
    }else{
     console.log('---date2 is greater-----');
    }
```

Comment: Do I put this in a click event? , because I did try that and it is not calling the click event

Comment: First of all, there is no need to format your date. Just compare them directly like inputDate1 > inputDate2. Second, you could just call form.validate() before saving or working further with data. Also the cleanest way would be to make custom validator for your form data, look here for example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-customvalidator?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

I was able to call the change event. My error was instead of using dateChange I was using change , which was not calling the event. So the correct function would be as :
{

<input matInput formControlName="tillDate" required             [matDatepicker]="pickerTillDate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" (dateChange)="onTillDate()"/>
}